# how to use pod package to package third libraries into the target

Tags: cocoapods, podspec

I have a framework project that has dependency private third libraries, i want to use pod package to pack the project so that users can only add one framework.
But the fact is the third libraries didn't pack into the final framework.

My package commond is 'pod package TestPod.podspec --no-mangle --force'

And this is my spec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "TestPod"
  s.version      = "0.0.1"
  s.summary      = "A short description of TestPod."
  s.authors      = 'wangb'
  s.description  = <<-DESC
                    long desc
                   DESC
  s.homepage     = "http://EXAMPLE/TestPod"
  s.license      = "MIT"
  s.platform     = :ios, "7.0"
  s.source       = { :git => "https:mygitpath/TestPod.git"}
  s.source_files  = "TestPod/TestPod/*.{h,m}"
  s.public_header_files = "TestPod/TestPod/TestPodPublic.h"
  s.vendored_frameworks = "TestPod/TestPod/uAnalytics.framework"
  s.frameworks = "CoreTelephony", "SystemConfiguration"
  s.libraries = "sqlite3"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have find the answer, pod package not support for now!
https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-packager/issues/26